# Третий день как он здесь

Tags: спп

***Третий день как он здесь***

За Розенталем предложение не является сложноподчиненным неполным предложением, так как в главной части предложения не подразумеваются слова *прошло с того времени* или *прошло с того момента*, а следовательно, запятая перед "как" не ставится.

Разве в предложении не подразумевается, что третий день прошел с того момента, как он здесь?

Comment: Насчёт того, что "прошёл" не подразумевается, Розенталь прав. Но не исключено, что подразумевается "пошёл (идёт)": _(Пошёл) третий день, как он здесь (находится)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Третий день как он здесь* - это разговорная конструкция, где КАК  выполняет роль временной частицы. Если убрать инверсию, будет *Он здесь третий день как.* Сравните:

-*Ты давно здесь?*

-*Да уж третий день как*.(третий день как - слитное сочетание, является обстоятельством времени)

Чтобы признать *Третий день* **неполным двусоставным предложением** главной части СПП, нужно какое-то указание на присутствие сказуемого, например, обстоятельство времени: *Третий день **уже**, как он здесь*.

У Розенталя в примерах неполных предложений тоже есть обстоятельства времени:

> В составе сложноподчиненного предложения может быть неполное
>   предложение — в главной части или придаточной: 1) неполное в главной
>   части: Вот **уже** два года, как мы женаты (ср.: Мы женаты вот уже два
>   года — простое предложение); **Уже** месяц, как он вернулся с юга (ср.: Он
>   уже месяц как вернулся с юга — запятая перед союзом как «оторвала» бы
>   сказуемое от подлежащего); **Уже** три недели, как мы здесь (ср.: Мы уже
>   три недели как здесь — обстоятельство места выражено сочетанием как
>   здесь); но: **Третий день как он здесь — простое предложение,** тогда как
>   в приведенных выше примерах в главной части предложения
>   подразумевались слова: прошло с того времени, с того момента.

– Alex_ander справедливо пишет:

> Но не исключено, что подразумевается "пошёл (идёт)": (Пошёл) третий
>   день, как он здесь (находится).

Да, не исключено, подразумевать мы можем многое, особенно в диалоге в коротких ответах, но там мы будем подразумевать, имея контекст. Если же контекста нет, то на пропуск сказуемого должно что-то указать из состава сказуемого, вот как здесь обстоятельство "уже", ведь обстоятельство - состав сказуемого, значит, и оно само здесь присутствует, предложение двусоставное. Вот в предложении *Как он здесь* на неполноту двусоставного предложения указывает обстоятельство места *здесь*.

Поэтому предложение *Третий день как он здесь* справедливо признано простым предложением.

Comment: Людмила, не хочу встревать в ваш разговор с другим участником, поєтому вопрос тут. *Вы же определили главное предложение как номинативное, но придаточное-то временное, а временное может относиться к сказуемому, к глаголу в нём, ведь придаточное времени уточняет время события, о котором говорится в главном.* - интересная трактовка. Не сталкивался с подобной логикой. Одна вещь непонятна. Это запрет грамматический. что придаточное не может относиться к опущенному (но явно подразумеваемому) члену? Или же это просто логическое обоснование подобного? С контрпримерами у меня пока туго, ищу.

Comment: @behemothus, это не просто  "интересная" трактовка, по определению временные придаточные содержат указание на время совершения действия или проявления признака, о которых говорится в главной части предложения. Я говорю лишь о грамматическом запрете присоединения обстоятельственного придаточного к именному. Именное может быть главным только для придаточного определительного, но не для временного.

Comment: Неполное двусоставное может сочетаться с придаточным, но чтобы оно было двусоставным, чтобы говорить о пропуске  сказуемого, оно должно быть эллиптическим, диалогически неполным, контекстуально, ситуативно неполным  ( у нас нет такого) или в его составе должно быть слово из состава сказуемого - обстоятельство или дополнение. Просто так подставить ничего нельзя. Я только об этом.

Comment: Ясно. То есть это все-таки весьма локального действия правило. Да вот не встречал я в грамматики явных указаний на такие запреты. Потому и назвал "интересной" трактовкой. Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: И все-таки интересный вопрос, может ли прижаточное (хоть какое-нибудь) соотноситься с элииптическиким членом. Если от вет "не может", то ваше аргументация - просто излишне многословное сужение более общего правила. и похоже ответ именно такой.  То есть все возражение автору того расзбора сводится до дной фо\разы. ***"Придаточное не может соотноситься с опущенным членом"***. Все. Умному достаточно )))).

Comment: Ну вот в моём ответе трактовка Розенталя: " В составе сложноподчиненного предложения может быть неполное предложение — в главной части или придаточной: 1) неполное в главной части: Вот уже два года, как мы женаты ; Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга; Уже три недели, как мы здесь.

Answer (score 1):

> Разве в предложении не подразумевается, что третий день прошел с того
> момента, как он здесь?

Нет. Не подразумевается. По смыслу - может быть, но грамматически подобное не предполагается.

Вот смотрите, как Кузнецов разделяет эти два случая.

> **КАК I местоим. нареч.**
> 4. Употр. для обозначения времени действия или проявления какого-л. состояния; в то > когда. Когда зайдёшь? - Да вот как из отпуска приеду.
>
> ...
>
> **КАК III. союзн. сл.**
>
> 4. (присоединяет придат. предл.). Употр. для выражения временных отношений. Перед
>    тем как уехать, он зашёл попрощаться. Прошёл год, как
>    мы не виделись.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&all=x

В первом случае нет грамматической основы основного (якобы) предложения. Ваш случай примыкает к этому варианту вся конструкция выполняет функцию наречия времени - и отвечает на вопрос "Сколько (времени)?" или "Какое время?". В принципе-то "как" в подобных конструкциях обычно можно опустить: "он здесь неделю/месяц/год".   Или даже "Третий день он здесь". Получается, что **как** грамматической роли союзного слова не несет.

Некоторая сложность заключается в том, что измеримость времени ("сколько?") вызывает некоторые сомнения, этим и определяется некоторая избыточность формы с "как", но современными грамматиками (вроде бы) признается без ограничений.

Comment: Тогда почему в "Уже три недели, как мы здесь." запятая? Тут "как" тоже можно опустить.

Answer (score -1):

Предложение выглядит как сложноподчинённое.

"Как" — временной союз.
Он здесь — грамматическая основа второй части.
Третий день — односоставное предложение. Глагол отсутствует.

Смысл такой:
*Третий день (уже с тех пор), как он здесь.*

Но Розенталь объединяет всё в единое простое предложение — в следствие краткости элементов.

То же самое можно наблюдать в теме ["цельных выражений"](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146). Более того, думаю, это и есть цельное выражение в трактовке Розенталя — и в этом всё дело.

Comment: *По структуре — это сложноподчинённое предложение* - господь с вами. Где у него две основы?

Comment: Такая авторская интерпретация не ошибочна, если подразумевается пропущенный глагол: *Третий день (уже идёт), как он здесь.* При этом перед "как" делается пауза.

Comment: Вы же определили главное предложение как номинативное, но придаточное-то временное, а временное может относиться к сказуемому, к глаголу в нём, ведь придаточное времени уточняет время события, о котором говорится в главном. Так что номинативным главное не может быть по определению, тем более, что Вы сами добавляете "уже с тех пор".

Comment: @Людмила А что в номинативном предложении глагол не может подразумеваться по смыслу? И при чём здесь "уже с тех пор"? Оно что отменяет номинативность? || Не утверждаю, что предложение сложноподчинённое, а лишь то, что по задумке автора его можно так интерпретировать - так как структура позволяет.

Comment: @oleedd, в номинативном (назывном ) предложении глагол не может подразумеваться по смыслу, он там не нужен совсем. Субстантивные (именные) односоставные предложения не содержат в составе глагольных форм, так как не выражают значения действия или процесса, а имеют значение бытийности в настоящем времени или вне времени, именно поэтому назывное пр. не может сочетаться с придаточным времени, уточняющим время события, о котором говорится в главном. Когда? "Уже с тех пор" - обстоятельство времени, состав сказуемого, а его не может быть в назывном, значит, это не назывное предложение.

Comment: @Людмила ОК. Удалил "номинативное" из ответа. || Частица "как" не выполняет данную функцию в толковых словарях. Вид "временных частиц" не удаётся найти в классификациях. Если союз превращается в частицу - то и смысл предложения должен меняться. Но он совсем не меняется, если убрать/добавить слово "уже". Это всё тот же временной союз, но, похоже, в составе цельного выражения, первая часть которых также односоставна. Такое возможно?

Comment: Удаляйте и "односоставное", если  глагол опущен, это неполное двусоставное или эллиптическое. Но дело даже не в этом, дело в том, что на СПП здесь указывает только союз КАК, но здесь он входит в цельное выражение, которое  занимает место одного члена предложения, его можно заменить одним словом "долго" . Поэтому я и назвала КАК усилительной частицей, ведь союз соединяет  однородные члены или простые  предложения в сложном, а здесь он только усиливает значение "третий день".

Comment: А вот наречие УЖЕ как раз добавляет значение времени, это обстоятельство времени, относящееся к пропущенному сказуемому. Если бы оно присутствовало, это было бы неполное двусоставное предложение. О номинативных почитайте подробнее здесь: https://studwood.ru/1342682/literatura/nominativnye_odnosostavnye_predlozheniya

Comment: @Людмила Вот и я думаю, что это цельное выражение. А в цельных выражениях перед союзом или местоимением запятая не ставится. Но в другие части речи эти элементы всё-таки не превращаются - иначе менялся бы смысл. "Как" ничего не усиливает, а всё так же означает "с тех пор как" или "от когда". Но структура цельных выражений всё равно являет собой основную и придаточную части. Но эти части настолько близки в следствие своей краткости, что запятая особо и не нужна.

Comment: По Вашей ссылке:"Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения. Так, в сочетании говорит об этом где только может выделенные слова имеют значение ‘везде’.
Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных словосочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологизма, то оно может образовать придаточную часть (обычно неполное предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно — ‘везде’;

Comment: @Людмила Просто имел в виду, что цельные выражения **выглядят** структурно как основа + придаточное. Но пунктуационно они так не оформляются. Структура - это ведь не только состав по официальной терминологии, а и условное деление на составные части по любым критериям. В ответе имеется в виду то же самое.